# How does Nutch's plug-in system work?

Tags: lucene, nutch

I am new to Nutch, but I know Nutch uses Lucene for indexing, which only understands text format.

Nutch has many plug-ins that are used for crawling documents with a particular format.

My doubt is: how does actually the Nutch plug-in system?

I seen the Team wiki page for [nutch](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/PluginCentral)

I'd like some information like how actually Nutch works with Lucene.

Answer (score 1):

All Lucene does is provide a way for "[Documents](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/api/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html)" to be added into a structured index and for queries to be executed against that index.

The Nutch crawler (I assume that's what you mean by nutch) just provides an easy way to get unstructured data (ie a website) to get pushed into the index. Just like you can use Solr to easily push xml data into a lucene index.

Nutch plugins simply provide a hook were you can put customer logic. For instance the "[parse-pdf](http://nutch.apache.org/apidocs-1.1/org/apache/nutch/parse/pdf/PdfParser.html)" can convert a binary PDF file into one of these "lucene Documents". Basically all it does is use an API that can read PDF documents ([pdfbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)) to extract the text (this is similar to what "parse-html" does since html has a lot of parts that isn't text, for example all html tags).

So regarding your concern about binary formats, its not difficult to parse, just difficult to get something useful. For instance we can write a "parse-image" plugin that could extract a lot of info about the image (ie name, format, size), it's just that parsing the "face" or the "dog" in the picture is difficult.